# Speeding up a function

Tags: function-construction, performance-tuning

This is un updated version of a previous (now deleted) post of mine.

I need to marginalize a distribution. I was suggested to use the code in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28216/function-to-marginalize-a-table-over-given-parameters?lq=1) thread. This works just fine, but the problem is that the construction of tab (see below) is very slow: I tried with a pTab[i] with 100 elements and it took 2 days on my dual core 2GHz laptop to build it, and my actual pTab[i] are 180000 elements long.

I guess you understand why I am worried.

Does anyone have any idea about how to speed it up?

Or a different code, maybe?

Here is the code I am using (only the slow part):

```
dat = (*Import data from dat.txt*)
mat = (*Import matrix from matrix.txt*)
nosys = Inverse[mat];
z = dat[[All, 1]];
mu = dat[[All, 2]];
H = ConstantArray[1, 580];
chi[{a_, b_, c_, 
   e_}] = (5/
      Log[10]*(Log[z] + 0.5*z*(3 - b) + 
        1/24*z^2*(21 + 9*b^2 - 2*b - 4*c)) - 
     mu).nosys.(5/
      Log[10]*(Log[z] + 0.5*z*(3 - b) + 
        1/24*z^2*(21 + 9*b^2 - 2*b - 4*c)) - 
     mu) - (H.nosys.(5/
         Log[10]*(Log[z] + 0.5*z*(3 - b) + 
           1/24*z^2*(21 + 9*b^2 - 2*b - 4*c)) - 
        mu))^2/(H.nosys.H) + ((a - 0.742)/0.024)^2 + ((e - 0.315)/
     0.017)^2;

ClearAll[pTab];

val = (*Import values needed for Ptab from ptab_values.txt*)

d = 4;(*number of parameters*)
Do[pTab[i] = val[[All, i + 1]], {i, d}];
tab = Module[{T, n}, 
   With[{F = chi}, 
    Replace[Hold[
       Array[Append[T, F[T]] &, Length[pTab[#]] & /@ Range[d]]] /. 
      T -> Table[Hold[pTab[n][[Slot[n]]]] /. n -> i, {i, d}], 
     Hold[x_] :> x, {0, Infinity}, Heads -> True]]];
Print["packing array"]
tab // Developer`PackedArrayQ;
```

The needed files are:

[for ptab](http://rapidshare.com/share/4E419B07B636867A13961DD119769094) (these are the numbers needed for building pTab (skip the first column: that is needed for another work))

[matrix](http://rapidshare.com/share/1616AA04C8BE98B60A6F554611278304) (a 580 x 580 matrix)

[for dat](http://rapidshare.com/share/7A12DD6E66C7B193A640DA59CB6821F3)  (only the first 2 columns are needed in this code)

Those are rapidshare links: I hope you allow it because the matrix is 580 X 580, and dat is 580 rows long: I can't write them in a post.

**EDIT:**
I was thinking can `Parallelize` be of any help in this case?

Comment: Do you think that `Parallelize` can be of any help?

Comment: You could provide fake data like this, I suppose: `nrec = 580; dat = RandomReal[1, {nrec, 2}]; mat = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {nrec, nrec}];` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this?

The main issue is that the `chi` function takes almost 3 seconds to evaluate once, which I did not investigate further.  Compiling it speeds it up by factor of about 17000!  Making the compiled function `Listable` and setting `Parallelization -> True` reduces the time of the whole program by another 30%.

Second, it's usually better to deal with arrays as arrays.  The `tab` code below takes about half of the time as the code in the OP, but some of that is due to the listability and parallelization of `chiCF0`.

The whole program takes a little less than 0.03 seconds.  It may still not be fast enough to switch from 580 elements to 180000, though.

```
ClearAll[pTab];
pTab = Transpose[val[[All, 2 ;; d + 1]]];

chiCF0 = Compile[{{arg, _Real, 1},
                  {z, _Real, 1}, {nosys, _Real, 2}, {H, _Real, 1}, {mu, _Real, 1}},
   Module[{a = arg[[1]], b = arg[[2]], c = arg[[3]], e = arg[[4]]},
    (5/Log[10]*(Log[z] + 0.5*z*(3 - b) + 
           1/24*z^2*(21 + 9*b^2 - 2*b - 4*c)) - 
        mu).nosys.(5/
          Log[10]*(Log[z] + 0.5*z*(3 - b) + 
           1/24*z^2*(21 + 9*b^2 - 2*b - 4*c)) - 
        mu) - (H.nosys.(5/
             Log[10]*(Log[z] + 0.5*z*(3 - b) + 
              1/24*z^2*(21 + 9*b^2 - 2*b - 4*c)) - 
           mu))^2/(H.nosys.H) + ((a - 0.742)/0.024)^2 + ((e - 0.315)/
        0.017)^2
    ],
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True
   ];
chiCF = chiCF0[#, z, nosys, H, mu] &;

tab = Module[{params = Tuples[pTab]},
  ArrayReshape[
   Transpose@Append[Transpose[params], chiCF[params]],
   Append[Table[d, {d}], d + 1]]
  ]
```

Comment: I am sorry it took so long for accepting, but it works tha kyou!

Comment: @mattiav27 No problem -- and you're welcome!